# struct initialization using curly brackets

Tags: c++

Saw some codes like below in a C++ project:

```
struct Foo{ 
    std::wstring x; 
    //blah
}

// this func returns a Foo object 

Foo getFoo(){ 
    //blah 
}

void main() { 
    Foo obj{getFoo()}; //why can initialize by another Foo object in {}? 
}
```

`{}` is list-initialization. But no `Foo` arguments are listed here. Why does   this work? Does struct have default copy constructor?

And does `Foo obj(getFoo())` work? Any difference from the way of using `{}`?

Comment: 1. `Foo` has an implicitly declared copy constructor; 2. `Foo obj(getFoo())` works too; 3. Same effect here.

Answer (score 1):

This is copy initialization. It calls the implicitly declared copy-constructor. Sources: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor